# How do I indicate failure in Task Scheduler?

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, taskmanager

When I look at the History tab of the Windows Task Scheduler, all of the entries are "Information".  Even when an error is thrown within the Task.

I would like to enter Error and/or Warning messages into the history so an observer can easily see that there was a failure without having to look at the Operational Code or into the System Event log.
It will be MUCH easier to find issues if there is a red "Error" circle or a yellow "Warning" triangle in the first column.

I have researched enough to know that the Task Scheduler doesn't consider it an error if the Task errors out. That's a valid, if annoying, point of view.

But I hold out hope, because in the Event Viewer I can open:

Applications and Services Logs | Microsoft | Windows | TaskScheduler | Operational

and see the same information.

The job I have in mind, I expect it to be in production for years to come.

The first debugging step for a scheduled task that fails... (and all jobs fail eventually)... is to look in the Task Scheduler's History tab!

Wouldn't it be great if the person looking (maybe even me) could see warnings and errors in History that could lead them to the solution quickly?

Here's a paired down sample of PowerShell code which doesn't achieve what I want:

```
param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$False)]   # 
    [string] $DestDir = "C:\Temp"
    )
#  ^-------param MUST BE FIRST LINE of file      
#
#I know that I can get an Error into the Application event log this way:
# •Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source EventSystem -EventID 5150 -EntryType Error -Message 'Directory Not Found Exception'
#
# BUT, I want to see something that indicates there was an error within the Task Scheduler's History tab!

"• Begin"
    if( !(Test-Path $DestDir -pathType container))
    {   # Error, throw DirectoryNotFoundException with the error text
        throw [System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException] "$DestDir is not a reachable folder"
    }
"• End"
```

My question is, how can I enter/cause messages that show up in History that are not Level = "Information"?

I have dug up that the Task Manager's History tab is the Log/Channel identified as "Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational" but I haven't been able to leverage this piece of data (can't yet write there & using it in internet searches hasn't helped either).

Thanks!

Comment: The following command should do what you want: `wevtutil.exe query-events Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational /format:text /query:"*[*/EventID=201][*/Data[@Name='ResultCode']!=0]"`. This queries the event channel "Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational" for all events with ID 201 (action success) for which the result code is non-zero. You may want XML output instead if consuming this in a scripting language. A similar query can be executed in PowerShell, if you prefer. Or use the Event Log API, e.g. [`EvtQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385466).

Comment: Also, if you prefer the GUI event viewer, you can add this as a filter under "Custom Views". Select to edit the XML query manually and enter `<QueryList><Query Id="0" Path="Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational"><Select Path="Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational">*[*/EventID=201][*/Data[@Name='ResultCode']!=0]</Select></Query></QueryList>`.

Comment: @eryksun please post answers as answers, not comments.

Comment: @briantist, the OP never replied to me. I prefer to work in comments at first to investigate an issue and get feedback from the OP about whether they actually understand what I'm saying, have tried it, and it works for them. Once I have a satisfactory understanding of the problem and solution, I can delete my comments and write it up as an answer, or the OP can write the answer, or sometimes someone else might. Eventually if I don't get feedback, I may add an answer or simply delete my comments. The OP seems to have gone on vacation. Are you here because you have a similar problem?

Comment: @eryksun - I'm sorry I didn't reply earlier, I didn't realize you were proposing this as an answer.  Unless I have misunderstood, it appears as though you have given me two good/valid/new ways to query the event viewer and see events related to TaskScheduler.  Thank you for that, however, what I would really like is a way to make a non-201 event appear there.  I.e. I want to _see_ a 'non-information' message _within_ the Task Scheduler's History (within the task scheduler).  Sorry if this wasn't clear, or if I misunderstood either of your comments/answers.

Comment: @eryksun (continued; ran out of space)  Please note that I up-voted both of your comments as useful last month (but, I guess you can't tell it was me).  I _do_ appreciate them.

Comment: @eryksun it's for the above reason that it _should_ be an answer. It doesn't matter that he didn't initially respond or that it didn't completely answer the question; it was helpful to him and more importantly, may be helpful to other readers who come across this question. Comments can be deleted at any time. There's good info there that should be in an answer.

Comment: I know I didn't try to solve the problem as stated. I thought the query I gave in the first comment could be used in the primary application to display an error log to the user, which seems like a better idea than trying to hack the task scheduler's event log.

Comment: @eryksun - Yes, normally I'd agree.  In this case the primary application runs unattended in the middle of the night under a service account; there isn't a user interface.  There are recon jobs written by others to verify the execution and integrity of my job.  Hacking the task scheduler's event log is, in my opinion, the best way to shorten the amount of time spent in search of a bug when it inevitably happens. "Hacking" in this case _only means_ adding "non-success" to the Task Scheduler's event log which seems to be a subset of the normal event log (which supports non-success messages). HTH